# Wrong number of template arguments error

Tags: c++, templates

I'm new to templates and trying to use my functions that are out of the class to adapt to the generic programming. But wenn I do this:

```
template<int C, int D>
class A{
    ...
}

float function(number<int C, int D> value);
```

it leads to following error:

```
Error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
float function(number<int C, int D> value);
                               ^
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: "Am I missing something here? " - Well, *we* certainly are. What is `number` ? Or did you mean `A`, as in `template<int C, int D> float function(A<C,D> value)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define template arguments on the function and forward them to the type:

```
template<int C, int D>
float function(number<C, D> value);
```